# no modulo names torch after installed using pip

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda

**Hi, i am very confused about this. i used pip to install torch 1.12 but when i import torch in a python console it says no such modulo. Can anyone help me ?  the link is a screenshot which you can see that if i use "pip3 show torch", it says i have torch1.12 installed. However, i still cannot import torch
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLYqx.png**

Comment: If you using python3 then use `pip install torch` to install the package and run like this `python3 program_name.py` in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `python <filename>.py`, You need to use `py <filename>.py`. Works for me.

**Demonstration**
**using `python`**
[image]
See how it's giving me an error.

**Using `py`**
[image]
It's working!